# C tokenize and analyze csv file

Tags: c, struct, io, token

I am learning about how to use token to analyze file and put it in struct array. My code compiles fine, but it crashes while running it. Can someone please help?

Here is my code:

```
struct state_info {
    char code[3];
    unsigned long num_records;
    unsigned long total_income;
    unsigned long total_vehicles;
    unsigned long total_population;
    unsigned long total_rent;
    unsigned long total_renter;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int num_states = 100;
    struct state_info *states[num_states];
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[i], "r");
    analyze_file(file, states, num_states);
}

void analyze_file(FILE *file, struct state_info *states[], int num_states) {
    const int line_sz = 100;
    char line[line_sz];
    while (fgets(line, line_sz, file) != NULL) {
        char* token = strtok(line, " \n");
        while(token != NULL) {
            //allocate memory
            int size = atoi(token);
            if(states[size] == NULL) {
                states[size] = malloc(sizeof(struct state_info));
                states[size]->num_records = 0;
                states[size]->total_income = 0;
                states[size]->total_vehicles = 0;
                states[size]->total_population = 0;
                states[size]->total_rent = 0;
                states[size]->total_renter = 0;
            }
            //add value to the states
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            strcpy(states[size]->code, token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            states[size]->total_population += atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            states[size]->total_income += atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            states[size]->total_vehicles += atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");

            //calculate total rent and total renter
            if(atoi(token) != 0) {
                states[size]->total_rent += atoi(token);
                states[size]->total_renter++;
            }
        }
        states[size]->num_records++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
}
```

I think there should be something wrong with my pointer but I am not sure about it.

Comment: check `token`. I bet it's `NULL` right after the second `strtok` call.

Comment: you're reading a line, so there can only be one token. At some point, `strtok` returns NULL but you're not testing against NULL each time you perform a `strtok` call.

Comment: `states[size]`is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Statement `struct state_info *states[num_states]` does not initialize the pointer array with `NULL`-values, such that it may contain "garbage" (i.e. pointers != `NULL` pointing to something not being a valid object).

Hence, a comparison like `if(states[size] == NULL)` will probably never evaluate to true and will consequently never allocate a proper object. Subsequent access to `states[size]` will lead to undefined behaviour (actually the access `states[size]==...` already is undefined behaviour, yet I bet that the "crash" is due to the subsequent access)

Maybe there are other issues as well; yet I think that this is the most obvious thing in your code.

Fix it by initialising `states`, e.g. `struct state_info *states[num_states] = { NULL }`

Comment: Or, better yet, initialize with `struct state_info *states[num_states] = { NULL };`